# BottomNavigationView change item Icons with different tint colors

Tags: android, android-drawable, bottomnavigationview, android-custom-drawable

The title may seem a bit confusing, sorry didn't know how to make it one line question.

I have a custom Drawable with different colors. However, when applied on a `BottomNavigationView` the btv applies tint on it and now it looks awful. Any way to solve this?

The thing is, because clicking on that specific drawable with colors will popup a `BottomSheetDialog`, I don't care about the color when pressed. Just that the drawable retains its own colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` to disable default tint color, then `onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)` you can change the drawable `item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_drawable));`

For more useful info check the [docomentations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView).